# Eliminating redundancy in multiple constructors

Tags: java, constructor, redundancy

If anyone could tell me whether my code is redundant (and if it is, possible solutions to eliminate redundancy) I would very appreciate it.

```
public class Question {
  private Queue<Double> a;

  public Question(double XXX) {
     a = new LinkedList<Double>();  // REDUNDANT?
     ......
  }

  public Question(double[] YYY) {
     a = new LinkedList<Double>();  // REDUNDANT?
     ......
  }
}
```

Basically, one constructor takes in a double value while the other constructor takes in an array of double numbers. Is there any way to instantiate the `Queue` only once?

Answer (score 3):

When using Java 7 and NetBeans or other IDEs, the IDE may flag

```
a = new LinkedList<Double>();
```

as redundant, you can use

```
a = new LinkedList<>();
```

instead.  But if you are just asking about actual redundancy in your code, use:

```
public class Question {
  private Queue<Double> a;

  public Question() {
     a = new LinkedList<>();
  }

  public Question(double XXX) {
     this();
     ......
  }

  public Question(double[] YYY) {
     this();
     ......
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the style I was looking for. Can't believe I didn't think of this...

Answer (score 3):

You can instantiate your variable a while declaring.

```
public class Question {
   private Queue<Double> a = new LinkedList<Double>();

   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `this` operator to call another constructor with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the field declaration:

```
private Queue<Double> a = new LinkedList<Double>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider this:

```
public class Question {
    private Queue<Double> a;

    public Question(double ... ds) {
        a = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(ds)));
    }
}
```

This uses the varargs constructor, to which you can pass a single double, multiple doubles, or an array of doubles. So you can do:

```
new Question(1, 2, 3);
new Question(1);
new Question(new double[] { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

**Note:** `ArrayUtils` is part of the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).